# Assistance Installing Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

Im running Debian 9. I have successful cloned go-ethereum from source on gitgub, and compiled it with the `make geth` command in go. I issued the `/build/bin/geth` command which successfully started the sync.

However, im confused where i would be entering the `geth` commands in order to create accounts? such as all the commands found here. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

How would i go about entering these commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start Geth, you get a javascript console and you can call web3 methods. Commands listed by the wiki is to setup geth. One example for you is **attach** command: geth **attach** ipc:/home/machine/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc

What is used for? If you start geth and start mining, your screen is going to get a lot of log messages and polute your view. So, you use **attach** command to open a new console so you can interact with geth console without log messages.

And to create new accounts, you start geth and run this web3 command inside the console:
personal.newAccount()

And to display accounts:
eth.accounts
eth.coinbase (account that get the mining reward)

Comment: Is it normal to receive "bash: geth: command not found"?

Did i build it incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry, didn´t understand. You´ve said " I issued the /build/bin/geth command which successfully started the sync.". Is it syncing? If yes, you should not see that bash message